# ODBC connected to Access - Not showing tables for all users

Tags: ms-access, odbc, quickbooks

I've been working to create an ODBC connection from my company's Quick Books file to an Access 2010 database. I'm pulling only two tables from Quick Books: Customers and invoices. So far it works beautifully on my computer. I can view both the Customers and Invoices tables. However, when I try to open the *invoices* table on another users computer in the Access database, I just get blank columns with no data being pulled through with no error message is generated. The customers table works fine.

This sounds like it might just be a Quick Books permissions issue but both the other user and I have the exact same permissions. The other user also has full access to invoice information.

I'm pretty desperate to find a solution to this as I've been working at it for a month now and can't find any reason why the other user can't view the Quick Books invoices table in the Access database.

I should mention that the Access database is being uploaded to a propitiatory database designed using MySQL.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Evan

Comment: I had the same issue long time ago. Meaning. I have users who donot have access to the remote database. so, I was not able to use the linked tables directly. 

That said, I would not recommend to do that too, if you have many non technical users.As this would increase your work load of setting up ODBC connection on each machine. I have the added the approach/solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I created a local table of the remote table and changed my quires to point to the local table instead of linked table.

If you would like the approach read the instructions below on how to resolve the issue.

1. Create a Local table same as linked table. Make sure that table structure does not change. The easiest way to create a local table from linked table is Rt.Click on the linked table and choose the option create Local Table from the menu and when prompted, Just choose structure not the structure+date
2. Make sure you still have Linked table, if you don't Map it back again
3. Then create a append query to pull data from the remote table and append to the local table.
4. The only over head with this is, you have to some how kick off the append query to keep the local table upto date.( I automated this step to update the data with a click of a button  another alternative option is to update the table when ever it is opened.

I hope this helped.  if you need additional help with VBA code reply here with link to sample db. i will try to code it for you.

Thank you

Comment: Hello, Thanks so much for your response. I ended up giving up completely on the ODBC driver and am now using another program that pulls data from QuickBooks (OpenSync). This program has it's own problems but I'm able to pull the Customer and Invoice tables into an Access database to be viewed by my colleagues. They don't even need QuickBooks installed on their computer. Pretty coo,.